Puerto Serial Java
Estoy intentando leer un puerto serial para obtener el valor que me da una bascula. He probado con 4 librerias diferentes y ninguna me lee el valor (sí está bien configurado el puerto porque desde una app de lectura de puertos la bascula si funciona, entonces si o si es el codigo el que falla)
Ojalá alguien me pueda ayudar, el código es:
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;

public class Pruebas {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SerialPort basculaPort = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM5");
        basculaPort.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, SerialPort.ONE_STOP_BIT, SerialPort.NO_PARITY);
        basculaPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING, 1000, 1000);

        if (basculaPort.openPort()) {
            System.out.println("Conectado a la báscula");

            try {
                // Si es necesario, envía un comando para solicitar el dato
                basculaPort.getOutputStream().write("COMANDO_A_ENVIAR\r".getBytes());
                basculaPort.getOutputStream().flush();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = basculaPort.readBytes(buffer, buffer.length);
                String data = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead).trim();

                System.out.println("Peso leído: " + data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                basculaPort.closePort();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se pudo conectar al puerto.");
        }
    }


Ya pude resolverlo, la solucion es tan simple como cambiar "COMANDO_A_ENVIAR" por una "p".
Antes:
basculaPort.getOutputStream().write("COMANDO_A_ENVIAR\r".getBytes());

Despues:
basculaPort.getOutputStream().write("P\r".getBytes());


O sea que el problema no era la librería, sino que el comando era otro. Por cierto, no tienes un manual explicando el formato de las peticiones y las respuestas?

@Mateo lo que hice fue buscar el modelo de mi bascula en google y en la página del fabricante encontré un manual donde venia toda la información de configuración de puerto. Yo creo que te puede funcionar la configuración que ya puse en el codigo de mi pregunta (porque leí que casi todas usan practicamente esa configuración), asi que solo revisa en que puerto COM conectaste la bascula y listo (esto último si tiene bastantes tutoriales, pero si no lo encuentras dime y te comparto un tutorial)

No tengo una báscula. En realidad quería decir, ¿Cómo supiste que había que cambiar eso por una p? ¿De dónde sacaste la información? Sería bueno que lo agregues a la respuesta. Además, estaría bien que agregues el modelo de tu báscula a la pregunta porque no creo que la comunicación de todas las básculas sea igual

Vi un video donde mostraban como leer el dato de una bascula con un software de basculas generico.  Esta persona es agena del área y mencionaba que desconocia porque solo leía cuando presionaba la letra "P" de su teclado.
Con esa casualidad hizo match en mi y pensé que el comando a enviar deberia ser una P. Solo fue una extraña coincidencia de no cerrar un video que no me iba a funcionar porque no era técnico (al final si funcionó)

En una búsqueda rápida encontré alguien más que tiene que enviar "P" para pesar y está en el manual. Concluyo que tu caso debe ser similar y puedes encontrar información sobre los comandos en el manual de tu báscula. Espero que el link te sirva.
